# Getting an array of facebook friends on iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, facebook

I have searched A LOT on the internet and I can't get this to work: How do i get an array of the user's facebook friends on iOS? All I need is an email address, full name and picture.

Here is what i have tried so far:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_friendlists", @"user_status", @"friends_status", nil] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        FBRequest* friendsRequest = [FBRequest requestForMyFriends];
        friendsRequest.session = FBSession.activeSession;

        [friendsRequest startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                      NSDictionary* result,
                                                      NSError *error) {
            NSArray* friends = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
            NSLog(@"Found: %i friends", friends.count);
            NSLog(@"friends: %@", result);
            for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend in friends) {
                NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend.name, friend.id);
            }
        }];
    }

}];}
```

The NSLogs don't log anything.

Now I get an error from the openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions call. It says:

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)" UserInfo=0x15673ed0 {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginDisallowedWithoutError, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=<FBSession: 0x15597540, state: FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed, loginHandler: 0x0, appID: 603086539749721, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x155a9020>, expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate: 0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}
```

Comment: Post what you have tried and what problem you are having.

Comment: OK, good, you've add some code. Please explain what it happening and what isn't working. Perhaps show the output from the logs.

Comment: As I have written above, the logs dont log anything. Using breakpoints I have discovered that it never even gets to that part(where the logs are), when it calls "startWithCompletionHandler" nothing happens

Comment: So you do reach the call to `startWithCompletionHandler:` but you never get inside the completion handler?

Comment: I used to reach the call. Now it changed it's behaviour somehow. Check the question, I've added the error.

Comment: If it worked moments ago but does not work anymore, it is really hard for us to trouble shoot without your code.. Did you mess with your app's bundle ID?

Comment: No I did not. It may have been my mistake. It is now consistently throwing the error I posted above, everytime I try to run the code.

Comment: The app doesn't even ask me for permission to access my friends.

Comment: Try signing out of facebook (in the app) and then try again. Is there any difference?

Comment: I havent signed in to facebook in the app. The code I have posted above is all I have done. I am signet into facebook on my iphone (from the settings app), so I thought that covers it.

Answer (score 0):

I think system is not allowed your application to access Facebook.
To solve this error, please follow below steps:-
1. Go to Settings of your iPhone / iPad.
2. Find out Facebook & go to its settings. 
3. You'll find your app inside the listing with other apps.
4. Please turn the switch on & try to use Facebook from your app. (By default, it is off by system. So you have to go to settings & turn the application on to allow access Facebook.)

Hope it'll work for you. Thank You..!!